# Is it possible to dynamically create source sets?

Tags: gradle, source-sets

I am wondering if it is possible to dynamically create a source set with gradle. The directory hierarchy of my current project looks as follows:

- dbfit-junit

  - module

    - foo
    - bar

Each of this module folders (foo and bar) should have its own source set assigned. The reason is that I want to dynamically create tasks like dbFitTestFoo and dbFitTestBar. My current approach looks like this:

```
ext.dbFitModulesDir = "dbfit-junit/module"
ext.dbFitTestSpecs = ["java", "groovy", "scala", "resources"]  
ext.dbFitModules = []

file(dbFitModulesDir).eachDir{ module ->
    dbFitModules << module.name
}

/** this needs to be done dynamically for each "module" **/
sourceSets {
    integrationTest { sourceSet ->
        dbFitModules.each{ module ->
            dbFitTestSpecs.each { spec ->
                if (!sourceSet.hasProperty(spec)) {
                    return
                }
                sourceSet."$spec".srcDir file("$dbFitModulesDir/$module/$spec")
            }
        }
    }
}

dbFitModules.each{ module ->
    task "dbFitTest${module.capitalize()}"(type: Test) {
        group = "Verification"
        description = "Run dbFit tests for $module"
        doLast {
            testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
            classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
        }
    }
}
```

The creation of the tasks works smoothly, the only thing that is still missing is the dynamic creation and assignment of the sourcesets.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can create source sets dynamically. Here's one example:

```
dbFitModules.each { module ->
    sourceSets.create("${module}Test") {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Seems like one can do almost everything with Gradle, I love it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi, is there any reference to this _sourceSets.create_ method? I cannot find it... thanks!

Comment: You can find the method in the [Javadocs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectContainer.html#create(java.lang.String)). NamedDomainObjectContainer is  the parent class of [SourceSetContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSetContainer.html).